# How to force jboss to use all jars from webapp (.war)?

Tags: jboss, web-applications

I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/hibernate/Session.isDefaultReadOnly()` because jboss uses own libraries, not that from webapp.war. How to force jboss (5.1.0) to get proper jars ?

Comment: *bump* Did you ever get this figured out?